# Running wireless access server where the server is node.js

Tags: raspbian, wireless, web-server, node.js, media-server

I have created web server on raspberry pi using Node.js. I can access that server on my local network using ethernet cabel, but I would like to make nodejs server of wireless access point.

I have tried to search on google if anyone tried something similar to see how it was done, but with no results. All of the tutorials are using Apache HTTP server and PHP, so I don't know what I nedd and what I don't need.

I would be thankfull if somebody could point me in the right direction, on what I need to do to have wireless access point and node.js server on raspberry pi.

Any help is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  Are you just asking how to make your Raspberry Pi work over Wifi instead of Ethernet cable?  Or is this something else?

Comment: I would like to have Raspberry Pi working as a server, and also a wireless access point. I would like to have possibilitiy to connect my phone, computer, etc to the Raspberry Pi using WiFi.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to make a hotspot and web server available on the hotspot ip (say 192.168.1.1 ? ) I don't see why it is a problem. I suggest you to divide and rule. 1. Create a hotspot. 2. Host a simple apache server and see if it's working 3. Try replacing apache with your node.js server.